# Monitor disk usage changes to infer download speed

Tags: download-speed, network-monitoring

I'm testing various solutions for downloading large datasets, downloads which can take weeks and require several restarts. Instead of monitoring network speed, I'd like to use the change in disk usage to infer download speeds, since this will avoid measuring re-transmission of failed transfers. Is there a tool to do this, or should I roll my own bash solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coreutils are well suited to this kind of thing. Here is a quick solution that will also save the dates and times.

```
$ echo -e "$(date)\t$(df | awk '$1 == "/dev/sda1" {print $2}')" > df_1
<wait a while>
$ echo -e "$(date)\t$(df | awk '$1 == "/dev/sda1" {print $2}')" > df_2
$ echo "$(( $(awk '{print $2}' FS='\t' df_2) - $(awk '{print $2}' FS='\t' df_1) )) K increase from $(awk '{print $1}' FS='\t' df_1) to $(awk '{print $1}' FS='\t' df_2)"
12 K increase from Wed Nov 20 21:22:07 EST 2013 to Wed Nov 20 21:23:13 EST 2013
```

I'm not sure if you need this, but to explain what it does:

- Firstly, save the current date and time (`date`), and "used" disk space (`awk '$1 == "/dev/sda1" {print $2}'`) into the file `df_1`. You might need to substitute your specific file system instead of `/dev/sda1`. Use `df` alone to get a list.
- Secondly, repeat at a later date.
- Finally, print out the difference between the "used" disk space `$((...))`, which was stored in the first field of each file, and print out the dates (from the second field).

Comment: I guess I've rolled a bash solution for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sparhawk beat me to it, but here's my own solution, which I intended to run as a cron job

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp1=$(cat du-prev.txt | cut -f 2)
timestamp2=$(date +"%s")
timediff=$(echo "${timestamp2}-${timestamp1}" | bc)

current=$(du -s | cut -f 1)
previous=$(cat du-prev.txt | cut -f 1)
spacediff=$(echo "${current}-${previous}" | bc)

speed=$(echo "scale=2; ((${spacediff}/${timediff})*8)/1024" | bc)

echo "timediff   : ${timediff} sec"
echo "spacediff  : ${spacediff} KB"
echo "speed      : ${speed} Mb/s"
echo -e "${current}\t${timestamp2}" > du-prev.txt
echo -e "${speed}\t${timestamp2}" >> logs/speedlog.txt
```